# serving another version of google app engine application - custom subdomain SSL

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, https

I was able to configure SSL for .pl to serve my appengine app over https.

My application always require https. For testing purposes I would like to be able to serve another version of my app (one that I have already uploaded). However, going to `<app version>.<my domain name>.pl` doesn't seem to work (I was able to do this before enabling SSL).

I purchased another SSL cert, for `www.<app version>.<my domain name>.pl` and configured it similarly how I configured the SSL cert for the naked domain. The problem is that under assigning urls it says "no matching urls" and doesn't allow me to enter a url.

EDIT: Turns out I can sort of achieve this by going to my apps https://..appspot.com if I disregard browser warning. Works for testing purposes fine to my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the extend I understand your question, you might be suffering from WWW and NON-WWW issue. You have configured your certificate for www...pl which should be configured on ..pl

Still it is not cleared. I can help you more accurately if you can elaborate your question.

Comment: Thank you Jay! I tried both CSRs for www.<subdomain>.domain.pl and <subdomain>.domain.pl but neither worked. It's a PositiveSSL cert from Comodo. Now that I found out I can just use my appspot url for testing I think I will stick to using it and reissue the cert for another domain all together. Thank you very much though!

Comment: What you're saying in that article of yours is very misleading. The redirection from `https://www.example.com` to `https://example.com` is only useful [if *both* present a valid certificate (maybe the same)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24860789/372643). Wildcard SSL certificates are NOT sufficient. If you have a cert only valid for `*.example.com`, this will not work for `https://example.com`. The reason many wildcard certs work is that they're also certs with multiple SANs: one for `example.com` and one for `*.example.com`: it's the SAN for `example.com` that helps here, not the wildcard.